# Nested addEventListeners, blocked input Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, input, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a form that displays an output depending on two inputs.

Unfortunately the counting isn't proportion-able so I'm using couple of `case`'s in `if`'s.

I've got a table of dimensions and amount of an item. I.e.: if you choose two items of 85x200 dimensions, you'll pay 570 zł.

I don't know why, but now it looks like I have blocked two last options in my select. I can only choose the first one, and if I chose second or the third one, I still have the value of the first one counted.

**Code:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  "use strict";
  let amount = document.getElementById('amount');
  let size = document.getElementById('size');
  let spanPrice = document.getElementById('output');

  amount.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    const prices = document.querySelectorAll("td.price");
    let pricesArray = [...prices];
    size.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      function count() {

        if (size.value = "85x200") {
          if (amount.value <= 10) {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[0].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);
          } else if (amount.value <= 30) {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[1].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);
          } else if (amount.value <= 50) {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[2].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);
          } else {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[3].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);
          }
        } else if (size.value = "100x200") {
          if (amount.value <= 10) {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[4].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);

          } else if (amount.value <= 30) {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[5].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);
          } else if (amount.value <= 50) {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[6].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);
          } else {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[7].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);
          }
        } else {
          if (amount.value <= 10) {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[8].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);

          } else if (amount.value <= 30) {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[9].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);

          } else if (amount.value <= 50) {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[10].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);

          } else {
            return amount.value * pricesArray[11].innerHTML.slice(0, -6);

          }
        }
      }

      count();
      let result = count();
      spanPrice.innerHTML = result;
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="content">
    <h2>Roll-upy</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>wymiary</th>
          <th>1 - 10 sztuk</th>
          <th>11 - 30 sztuk</th>
          <th>31 - 50 sztuk</th>
          <th>powyżej 50 sztuk</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="85x200">
          <td>85 cm x 200 cm</td>
          <td class="price one-ten" id="one">285,00 zł</td>
          <td class="price eleven-thirty" id="two">239,00 zł</td>
          <td class="price thirtyone-fifty" id="three">229,00 zł</td>
          <td class="price above-fifty" id="four">205,00 zł</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="100x200">
          <td>100 cm x 200 cm</td>
          <td class="price one-ten" id="five">329,00 zł</td>
          <td class="price eleven-thirty" id="six">275,00 zł</td>
          <td class="price thirtyone-fifty" id="seven">245,00 zł</td>
          <td class="price above-fifty" id="eight">234,00 zł</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="120x200">
          <td>120 cm x 200 cm</td>
          <td class="price one-ten" id="nine">359,00 zł</td>
          <td class="price eleven-thirty" id="ten">319,00 zł</td>
          <td class="price thirtyone-fifty" id="eleven">299,00 zł</td>
          <td class="price above-fifty" id="twelve">245,00 zł</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label for="amount">Podaj ilość sztuk:</label>
      <input name="amount" id="amount" type="number" min="1" value="0" step="1"><br><br>
      <label for="size">Podaj wymiary:</label>
      <select name="size" id="size">
                <option>Kliknij, aby wybrać</option>
                <option value="85x200">85cm x 200 cm</option>
                <option value="100x200">100cm x 200 cm</option>
                <option value="120x200">120cm x 200 cm</option>
              </select>
      <p>Cena:&nbsp;<span id="output"></span><span>&nbsp;zł</span></p>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Dodaj">
    </form>
  </section>
</main>
```

This is the codepen of the issue:

https://codepen.io/wiktoriatomzik/pen/mpxJMg

Comment: please think about reorganizing your code structure. you should not add big blobs of code into event handlers that you define on the fly. instead try to just add small functions or lambdas that just reference a bigger function and supply it with arguments. you also define multiple change listeners. don't do that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am a JS noob and I know that's not the most elegant way to write it, but it's all I can do now. Can you please suggest me what should be changed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `if` statements. You've used `=` instead of `==` to compare things. `=` is for assignment which means that when you have something like this: `if (size.value = "85x200")` you're actually assigning the value of the `size` element instead of comparing it to a string.

Just change that (and all similar statements) to: `if (size.value == "85x200")`

Comment: This was extacly what I was looking for! Works for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo inside of your `if` conditions. To make it work, just replace following lines:

- `if (size.value = "85x200")` to `if (size.value == "85x200")`
- `if (size.value = "100x200")` to `if (size.value == "100x200")`

Comment: Thank you Taras! Works perfectly.